# Client can only emit once and "force new connection" duplicates the response.

Tags: node.js, socket.io

my client side can only emit once and "force new connection" duplicates the response back to my client. here's my code so you can look it up.

server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(5000);


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

   socket.on('sendSheet', function(data) {
      io.sockets.emit('displayData', data);

   });

   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      io.sockets.emit('user disconnected');
   });
});
```

client.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000', {'force new connection': true});
socket.on('dispatchConnect', function (data) {
    socket.emit('sendSheet', mergedForm);
});

socket.on('displayData', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about asynchronous functions in nodejs and try to understand "the node event loop".

Your code is blocking couse your functions are synchronous .

Since an event loop runs in a single thread, it only processes the next event when the callback finishes.

You should **never** use a blocking  function inside a callback, since you’re blocking the event loop
and preventing other callbacks - probably belonging to other client connections - from being served.

Here is a async example:

```
var myAsyncFunction = function(someArg, callback) { // simulate some I/O was done
    setTimeout(function() {  // 1 second later, we are done with the I/O, call the callback
        callback();
    }, 1000)
}
```